# how can I send an 'ogg' file in the body of my HTTP POST request?

Tags: node.js, http, post, httprequest, postman

I am working on a nodejs project which needs to get a response by making a POST request to the API in which I need to send an audio file (audio.ogg) in the body of request. In 'postman' we can do something like this by selecting the file from local and make request.

[image: click this for POSTMAN request demo]

How can I do the same with my Nodejs application using an npm package like 'request'?

My code so far is quoted here:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var options = {
    method: 'post',
    body: {
      'language': "<language>",
      'audio_file':path.join(__dirname, 'audio.ogg')

    }, // Javascript object
    json: true,
    url: "<API>",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': "<token>",
      'ContentType': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  }

  request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error :', err)
      return
    }
    console.log(' Body :', body)

  });
  // res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `options.headers`, since you're sending binary data, your ContentType should be "multipart/form-data" instead of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as binary data is noted to be inefficient to transfer using `x-www-form-urlencoded` (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073451/4276832) for details on why).

Luckily, the `request` library you are already using includes the `form-data` library for handling `multipart/form-data` requests.  `request` provides the `formData` option for this, which you would use *instead* of using the `body` option.

Your updated options object might look something like this:

```
var formData = {
  // Pass a simple key-value pair
  language: '<language>',
  // Pass data via Streams
  my_file: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/audio.ogg')
};

var options = {
    method: 'post',
    formData: formData,
    url: "<API>",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': "<token>",
      'ContentType': "multipart/form-data"
    }
}
```

For more info, check the documentation for `request` [here](https://github.com/request/request/tree/253c5e507ddb95dd88622087b6387655bd0ff935#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads)